# Derivative nonlinear Schrodinger equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm dealing with the following DNLS
$$iu_t+u_{xx}=i(|u|^2u)_x$$
Let's consider the following transformation $w=\exp(-i\int_{-\infty}^x|u|^2dy)u$. I'm interested in the equation satisfied by $w$. I should get
$$iw_t+w_{xx}=-iw^2\partial_x\bar{w}-\frac{1}{2}|w|^4w$$
But making the computations I get another expression.
I've found the following:
$$w_t=\exp(-i\int_{-\infty}^x|u|^2dy)u_t-iu\int_{-\infty}^x\partial_t(|u|^2)dy\exp(-i\int_{-\infty}^x|u|^2dy)$$
and analogous expressions for the other quantities appearing in the DNLS; putting all togheter I don't get the desired formula.I wrote only the expression for $w_t$ because I think it contains the problem. Does it contain some mistakes? 
Any suggestions will be apprecieted.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but if you substitute the expression $t^{-.25}f(\mu)$ where $\mu=\frac{x}{t^.5}$ for $u$, take derivatives and substitute, you get $i(f-\frac{\mu}{2}f_\mu)+f_{\mu \mu}=i(-3\mu f^2 f_\mu)$ for the DNLS, and $i(f-\frac{\mu}{2}f_\mu)+f_{\mu \mu}=if^2f_\mu-\frac{1}{2}|f|^4f$ for the equation satisfied by $\omega$.  Since these are ODE's, they might be easier to solve.  (Or not, they're fairly awful ODE's.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but maybe I've solved; it was just a matter of manipulating in a clever way some terms.